# R-package for variable importance in Hierarchical Clustering

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I am looking for a package in R which gives also the importance of variables for hierarchical clustering.

```
hcModel = hclust(dist(data),method="ward.D2")
```

There is an output called `order` which is not what I am searching for. It is only a grafical parameter, indeed it is a vector giving the permutation of the original observations suitable for plotting.

I've found the method `HCPC` of package `FactoMineR`, but it is not exhactly what I am looking for, because it is an Hierarchical Clustering on Principal Components.

Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks,